# How to fix infinite loop in navigationDestination, why this happens?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

What's wrong with navigationDestination with binding on ios 16? I have an infinite loop in nested navigation with binding and navigation stack

```
struct Visit: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    let name: String
}

struct ClientsListView: View {
    
    @Binding var selected: Visit

    var body: some View {
        Text(selected.name)
        .navigationTitle("Clients")
    }
}

struct VisitFormView: View {
            
    @Binding var selected: Visit

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Select client", destination: {
            ClientsListView(selected: $selected)
        })
        .navigationTitle("Visit form")
        .onAppear {
            print("form on appear")
        }
    }
}

class VisitsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [Visit] = {
        (0...30).map { Visit(id: $0.formatted(), name: "Test \($0)") }
    }()
}

struct VisitsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = VisitsViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<vm.list.count, id:\.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(value: index) {
                    Text(vm.list[index].name)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { id in
            let _ = print("VisitsView navigationDestination \(Date())") // infinite call print
            VisitFormView(selected: $vm.list[id])
        }
        .navigationTitle("Visits")
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                VisitsView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after I tap "select client" the result is an infinite loop, with a memory leak and 100% CPU

if I will remove binding from VisitFormView problem goes away. if replace navigationDestination to init(@ViewBuilder destination: () -> Destination, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) will work. I can resolve problems with the environment, but I want to understand what happens, and why loops. any help?

Comment: `navigationDestination` does not work with `Binding` you have to use `NavigationLink` with `destination` in it, hopefully there will be a better solution in a couple of weeks but as of no there is no solution for this just workarounds that half work.

Comment: @loremipsum in apple GitHub foodtrack app they use binding in navigationDestination as in my example. In my example first level works fine, but stack second nested navigation . Yes navigation link works, but why stack and infinite loop happens, what calling loop

Comment: I’ve seen that example and hopefully Apple will have a better solution. Apple needs to implement something like the modals work. There is no viable solution their example does not work and it iterates over the entire collection way too many times. You’ll find a half dozen “solutions” on SO and people have open tickets trying to find a viable solution but there isn’t anything right now.